# Производительность запросов SQL

Tags: sql, opensource, производительность, mysql

Изучая код в одном OpenSource`ном продукте, наткнулся на такой вот фрагмент кода, отвечающий за запрос к БД:

```
SELECT p.ID_PICTURE, p.views, p.filename, m.ID_MEMBER, m.realName, c.COUNT
FROM '.$this->db['prefix'].'gallery_pic AS p
JOIN '.$this->db['prefix'].'members AS m ON m.ID_MEMBER = p.ID_MEMBER
JOIN (
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT, ID_PICTURE FROM '.$this->db['prefix'].'gallery_comment
     ) AS c ON c.ID_PICTURE = p.ID_PICTURE
WHERE  p.ID_CAT = :id
ORDER BY p.DATE DESC
```

Посмотрев внимательно, станет ясно, что его можно разбить на 2-3 последовательных запроса в одну строчку кода. Собственно, вопрос в том как изменится нагрузка на сервер, если производить последовательные запросы, вместо вот таких огромных? Что если чаще придерживаться разбиения запросов на несколько, а не объединения их в один?

Comment: Хороший запрос. Разбивать его не &laquo;можно&raquo;, т.е. **нельзя**.

@jmu совершенно справедливо перечислил нюансы.

Answer (score 1):

1) выполнение нескольких запросов медленее
2) результат зависит от структуры субд
3) имеет смысл разбивать если вы можете какие-то данные кешировать

Comment: думаю стоит добавить ещё один вариант - если результаты промежуточных запросов большие, а результат маленький. То есть, пусть запрос можно разбить на два отдельных, но только результат первого - 10к строк, а результат второго - 5строк (это может быть в случае какой-нибудь агрегации).